# can i export sqlite database to csv and if so how?

Tags: sql

I have a database including 10 tables: (date ,day ,month ,year ,pcp1 ,pcp2 ,pcp3 ,pcp4,pcp5 ,pcp6) and each column has 41 years dataset. day, month and year columns are "Null" as l will add them later after exporting tables in csv file and l did this part but format is not correct as each column must be respectively separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not supposed to return the headers. Also I'm confident about both points below. This is untested, but the description attribute returns the last query table names, so it should work

About the extra blank line every line: I suppose you're using windows. Opening the output as text file add an extra \r (carriage return char). It's handled differently between python 2 and python 3:

It's actually OK, but you have the impression that it's not working because you're opening the csv with excel and excel requires a ; by default for csvs => you have to specify semicolon delimiter or Excel opens it on one column.